# Material Baking results in some black faces

Tags: materials, baking

I need to bake something for a unity project. Unfortunately I had an issue I ran into. I could solve it in unity but since this seems to be very odd I want to understand why this happens.

Here is a picture of the unbaked material:
[image]

Here it is after baking with an image node connected to an emission node:
[image]

Here are my bake settings:

[image]

I also tried it with only Diffuse / Color. The result is a mostly black image. Some faces are greyish:
[image]
[image]

All the other stuff I baked so far - I had no problem with them. 
What I tried so far:
- I unwrapped it again
- created a new image to bake it to
- recalculated normals

Thank you for every info you can give me on that.